# Fusion charts initial chart width not calculating based on container in ie 10

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-10, fusioncharts

Fusion charts initial chart width not calculating based on container in ie 10. The width of the chart is bigger than its container. Please find the markup below:

```
 <div class="col-lg-{{12/chartsPerRow}} col-md-{{12/chartsPerRow}} col-sm-{{12/chartsPerRow}} col-xs-{{12/chartsPerRow}}" ng-repeat="col in rows.columns" ng-switch on="col.type" ng-show="col.sel">
                <br>
                <div ng-switch-when="fchart" style="position:inherit;margin-right:5%;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888">
                    <div class="hovercontainer" style="height:200px;padding-bottom:0px" ng-style="{height:800/(chartsPerRow+1)}">
                        <fc-chart fc-chart-type="{{col.chartType}}" ng-model="col.chartdata" fc-data="col.chartdata" >
                        </fc-chart>
                     </div>
                 </div>
 </div>
```

works fine on ie11 and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the chart configuration for the chart that you are trying to render?
Generally if width and height is given in chart object while initialising, it will take that value.